# Find HTML Element that has Specific Attribute Using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I target an HTML element that has a specific attribute, but when that attribute has no value (well, whether it has a value or not). I've found others asking similar questions about elements with attribute *values* but not based on existence of the attribute itself.

For example, with this HTML:

```
<div id="id1">
  <div class="c1"></div>
  <div class="c2" an-attribute ></div>
  <div class="c3"></div>
</div>
```

How might I go about finding the `div` within `#id1` that has the attribute `an-attribute`? I can't count on it being in a particular location related to the other `divs` but can count on it being in `#id1`.

Comment: Something like: `$('#id1 *[an-attribute]');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

```
$('#id1 div[an-attribute]');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use an [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/):

```
$('div[an-attribute]') // or $('[an-attribute]')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div").children().attr("an-attribute");
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.  This code will retrieve the value of an attribute if you've already found an element.  The OP was asking how to find an element based on whether an element has an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code. i have used to identify the attribute.

HTML Code

```
<div id="id1">
        <div class="c1"></div>
        <div class="c2" id="testr">dd</div>
        <div class="c3"></div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript Code

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $('.c2').on('click',function(){
        var id =$(this).attr('id')
        alert(id);
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
alert($('[an-attribute]').attr('class'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div an-attribute class="111111111"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
       
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('[an-attribute]').css("color","red")

});
</script>

<div id="id1">
  <div class="c1">dsadsa1</div>
  <div class="c2" an-attribute >dsdsads2</div>
  <div class="c3">dsadsad3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var element=$('#id1').find('div[an-attribute]');
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanations